# hyperlinks in text boxes app inventor

Tags: listpicker, app-inventor

Since I cannot use activity starters in my listpicker, I want to include some youtube links in my text boxes of the listpicker. Is there a way to do this so that it actually is a hyperlink that goes to the youtube app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, see here [how to use the Activity Starter to view a Youtube Video](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2youtube)

You might want to use two lists, a "nice" list with names to be displayed in the listpicker and a second list with the URLs to the videos. Then in the AfterPicking event of the listpicker just use the selection index of the listpicker to get the corresponding item from the second list and start the activity starter as demonstrated in the example above.